# how to skip executing several lines with if clause in R

Tags: r, if-statement, skip

how to skip executing several lines of codes if a condition in IF statement is met. Condition happens occasionally so whenever it happens we need to skip executing several lines of codes, for example:

```
 if ( op=='A) {

     #skip doing everything here }
{

  #some line of codes which will be run in any condition
```

or is it possible to do it using `while` or `for` loops ?

Comment: I don't understand, you seem to have figured it out. Where is the issue?

Comment: i need to skip executing those lines a the block not executing them, this is what i do not know.

Comment: If you use `if ( op != 'A')` `#skip doing everything here` part will not be executed when `op == A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test the condition using

```
if (op != 'A') {
    #Code1
    #Code2
    #Don't execute this part for op == 'A' 
}

#Code3
#Code4
#Execute this part for everything
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `next` keyword. For example, the code below will not print the 
values in the vector `x = 1:10` from `5` to `8`:

> 

```
    x = 1:10
    for(i in x){ 
        if(i>=5 && i<=8){
            next #Skips printing when i=5,6,7 and 8
        }
        print(i) #Code you don't want skipped goes here
    }
```